# graphviz, straighten out skiplist?

Tags: graphviz

I have a digraph made up to draw a skiplist, which it does fairly well, but the alignment needs to be improved.

```
digraph {
  rankdir=LR
  node [shape=record,weight=4]
  edge [weight=10000]

  X [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>Head"]
  A [label="<f3>•|<f4>4"]
  B [label="<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>8"]
  C [label="<f3>•|<f4>15"]
  D [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>16"]
  E [label="<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>23"]
  F [label="<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>42"]
  Y [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>Tail"]

  X:f0 -> D:f0
  X:f1 -> B:f1
  X:f2 -> B:f2
  X:f3 -> A:f3
  X:f4 -> A:f4

  A:f3 -> B:f3
  A:f4 -> B:f4

  B:f1 -> D:f1
  B:f2 -> D:f2
  B:f3 -> C:f3
  B:f4 -> C:f4

  C:f3 -> D:f3
  C:f4 -> D:f4

  D:f0 -> Y:f0
  D:f1 -> Y:f1
  D:f2 -> E:f2
  D:f3 -> E:f3
  D:f4 -> E:f4

  E:f3 -> F:f3
  E:f4 -> F:f4

  F:f2 -> Y:f2
  F:f3 -> Y:f3
  F:f4 -> Y:f4
}
```

This produces: [image]

I would like to produce something more like this: [image]

How do I make the edges be straight? And how do align the nodes to be all on the same baseline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this graph, all that needs to be done is to add this to the graph:

```
nodesep=0
```

(You then may also remove the `weight` attributes)

> [`nodesep`](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/attrs.html#d:nodesep): specifies the minimum space between two adjacent nodes
>   in the same rank

The way I imagine it works, is that nodesep adds some padding to the sides of the nodes. If there is a nearby edge, the node will be moved to respect the padding.

Comment: Wow! For my personal benefit, could you explain what `nodesep` actually does? I don't see the connection between the distance of the nodes (which are not of the same rank) and the straight lines.

Comment: That thought make sense, but at the same time `nodesep` to me would suggest it would have the nodes touch with the arrows sitting on top. Odd, but works perfectly thanks.

Comment: @Drew `nodesep=0` will have them touch (almost, depending on the shape), at least the ones on the same rank. Between the ranks, `ranksep` determines the distance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to play around with the height of each individual node. Here is what I have done so far, gets close but you may want to further improve:

```
digraph so
{
  splines = line;
  rankdir = LR;
  node [ shape = record ];
  edge[ minlen = 2 ];

  X [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>Head", height = 5.5 ]
  A [label="<f3>•|<f4>4", height = 2.25 ]
  B [label="<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>8", height = 4.5 ]
  C [label="<f3>•|<f4>15", height = 2.25 ]
  D [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>16", height = 5.5 ]
  E [label="<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>23", height = 3.25 ]
  F [label="<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>42", height = 3.25 ]
  Y [label="<f0>•|<f1>•|<f2>•|<f3>•|<f4>Tail", height = 5.5 ]

  X:f0 -> D:f0
  X:f1 -> B:f1
  X:f2 -> B:f2
  X:f3 -> A:f3:w
  X:f4 -> A:f4

  A:f3 -> B:f3
  A:f4 -> B:f4

  B:f1 -> D:f1
  B:f2 -> D:f2
  B:f3 -> C:f3
  B:f4 -> C:f4

  C:f3:e -> D:f3
  C:f4 -> D:f4

  D:f0 -> Y:f0
  D:f1 -> Y:f1
  D:f2 -> E:f2
  D:f3 -> E:f3
  D:f4 -> E:f4

  E:f3 -> F:f3
  E:f4 -> F:f4

  F:f2 -> Y:f2
  F:f3 -> Y:f3
  F:f4 -> Y:f4
}
```

yields

[image]